# Font in Russian/Indian math papers

Tags: fonts

**Can someone tell me what font they used to typeset the following equations? (Math font)**

Thanks!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you can't find your font in document's meta-data, you can compare your guess with fonts listed in [The LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: @TeXnician No it's not a duplicate! I am asking for the math font, not the text font.

Comment: Where's the difference? If you have a PDF or something similar open the font information dialog.

Comment: @TeXnician will that give me the font they used in TEX for the MATH?

Comment: Yeah, because TeX embeds fonts. You will see text and math fonts there.

Comment: @TeXnician: I'm pretty sure it's not a TeX output. Note the smaller font in fractions and strange kerns around `-` in superscripts.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan You're probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Century Schoolbook (or some other Schoolbook). For XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX one could use TeX Gyre Schola Math which is pretty similar:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Century Schoolbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\newcommand{\efrac}[2]{\hbox{\footnotesize$\dfrac{#1}{#2}$}}

\begin{document}
Решите неравенство $\efrac{1}{x^2-15x+56}+\efrac{1}{x^2-19x+88}\leqslant0$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\efrac` tries to imitate the Russian typographic tradition to use eight point font for display math fractions (it looks like that in your example).

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally found the font :) I am currently doing a research about Russian maths exams, could you elaborate on the typographic tradition?

Comment: I can't say much on traditions. I prefer to just use what LaTeX offers. [This article](https://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/~g029/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf) lists some of them.